# How to Properly Select Custom Table

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello i am new on customizing acumatica i just created my custom table on MSSQL then i want to put it on my custom grid on acumatica so far here is where i am

```
[Serializable]
public class withholdingtaxx : IBqlTable
  {
    #region Atc
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Atc")]
    public virtual string Atc { get; set; }
    public abstract class atc : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<atc> { }
    #endregion

    #region Type
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Type")]
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public abstract class type : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<type> { }
    #endregion

    #region Description
    [PXDBString(400, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public abstract class description : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<description> { }
    #endregion

    #region TaxRate
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tax Rate")]
    public virtual string TaxRate { get; set; }
    public abstract class taxRate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<taxRate> { }
    #endregion

    #region Bir_form
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Bir_form")]
    public virtual string Bir_form { get; set; }
    public abstract class bir_form : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<bir_form> { }
    #endregion
  }
```

and then

```
 public PXSave<withholdingtaxx> Save;
        public PXCancel<withholdingtaxx> Cancel;


        public PXSelect<withholdingtaxx> MasterView;
        public PXSelect<withholdingtaxx> DetailsView;
```

[image]

am i doing it right because it repeat all of the first row

Also i cannot add a new row and save edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a good progress. Still you miss following:
1. You need to have either IsKey field or PXDBIdentity. In that case Acumatica will be able to see which rows are different
2. Consider adding service fields CreatedByID, LastModifiedByID. 
I'd recommend you to copy/paste it from base Acumatica source code from some class.